# Dictionary doesn't recognize key type (Updated)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have

```
func keyboardWillShow(aNotification: NSNotification)    {
        //Collect information about keyboard using its notification.
        let info = aNotification.userInfo
        let duration = (info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSValue) as Double
        let curve : AnyObject? = info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
        let kbFrame : AnyObject? = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().size
}
```

How can I get these to be read without the

**"[NSObject : AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'** " error?

In beta versions of xCode this had worked, but as of **xCode 6.1** it no longer works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userInfo is optional Dictionary, so you can use optional binding to unwrap value. And CGSize is a struct, not a object, so change AnyObject to CGSize.

```
if let info = aNotification.userInfo {
    let duration = (info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSValue) as Double
    let curve : AnyObject? = info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
    let kbFrame: CGSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue().size
}
```